# Crystal Reports 10 Clear Out Preview Results

Tags: crystal-reports-10

I have created a new report in Crystal 10 and generated preview results to validate it.  Seeing that is was valide I saved the report.  The probelm is each time I open the report in Crystal it goes right into the old preview results rather than running it fresh with paramitors.  How can I clear out those old results?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the "Save Data with Report" option which is probably toggled on.  Open your report, then click "File" and you should see "Save Data with Report".  Toggle that off and then save your report, it should save without the previous data.

To permanently disable this by default click on "File"->"Options"->"Reporting"->Uncheck "Save Data With Report".  I should note, unchecking this global setting makes it so when you create new reports it won't save data.  It does not undo it for reports that already have this set.

Also, to refresh your data if you leave the option you can press F5 from Crystal Reports or choose "Report->Refresh Report Data".  I highly suggest just disabling this feature though.  I've run into instances where it was generated from the server and always getting the cached data which is problematic because the end user couldn't force a refresh (if that makes sense).